# How to add a .dot file in a existing Microsoft word document by using vb or C# .net?

Tags: c#, vb.net, ms-word

I need to automate the adding templates (.dot) in existing word document.
I can open the existing document like below

```
Dim ObjWord As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
Dim wrdoc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document

Dim missing = Type.Missing
wrdoc = ObjWord.Documents.Open("D:\T_F\TandF_Sample.doc", missing, True, missing, missing, missing, _
                                   missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing)
```

After that i need to attach the template file ("D:\Temp.dot"). is it possible to do this?
anyone plz help me with sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wrdoc.AttachedTemplate = "d:\temp.dot"
```

Comment: Thanks now d:\temp.dot template is attached. How to enable the "Automatically update document styles" option (MsWord 2007). plz help me

Comment: Please look around the object model, and see what properties and methods are available to you.